# Git/GitHub: Access rights

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-remote

I've had a bit of a rough start with learning Git because I made a fairly large (twenty-ish) collection of files locally before eventually deciding that I want them on GitHub.  I'm using a Linux machine with the latest Ubuntu version.  This meant that most of the introductory material on how to use GitHub with Git wasn't helpful for me because most of them assume you have files starting on GitHub that you want to clone.  The act of cloning seemed to come with granting access rights to the repository or something like that.

Instead, I registered on GitHub, navigated my terminal to the folder I wanted to upload, ran `git init`, then `git add *`, then `git commit -m "start"` then `git push`.  It gave me some error, can't remember what it was at this point, but I've been fooling with it for the past couple days trying to get things to work.

Here's my current roadblock:  I recently ran a pull request hoping that would somehow settle access rights issues.  I did it, gave it my username and password, and it seemed to work.  However, now I locally removed a file with `git rm file1.txt`, and have a folder with a file that I've changed.  I run `git add *` and `git commit -m "file cleaning"` everything works.  When I then run `git push origin master` I get the error

```
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I've tried looking up instructions on how to handle this error, used `git remote add proj https://github.com/username/proj.git` and so on, doesn't seem to solve the problem.  When I run `git config --list` it prints

```
user.name=username
user.email=username@jemal.com
core.editor=atom
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
```

I tried looking up where my actual config files are but couldn't navigate to them (found `/usr/bin/git/` but that's the executable file or a shortcut to it, not sure which ... but it's not a folder) and tried to look up how I could maybe edit the config just using `git config ...` but I'm not finding out how.

At this point, I figured it's probably better to check in and see if there's some big or fundamental mistake I'm making rather than keep trying to chase down google searches.  A note: I couldn't find the "official" web address to try to link up to the GitHub repository so I just copied the address in the address bar and tacked `.git` to the end.  I recall years ago the site would actually give you a copy-able link but I can't find that anymore.  This might be the source of my problems.

Comment: I'm kind of lost. I have "pushed" into github after starting from a project locally. What I do in these cases is:

- Work locally and do lots of commits.
- I decide I will set it up on github so I create a new empty repository on github.
- Add the new empty repo as a remote to my local project.
- Push into the empty repo.

It has worked like a charm so far.

Comment: @Edmundo That sounds like what I've tried to do but it hasn't worked for me, although maybe I'm misunderstanding how what you describe is different from what I'm doing.

Comment: I describe you below how to rename the remote

Comment: Gave username/password? I see two questions that are talking about github and not using ssh certificates and now I'm wondering if my assumptions (as in: for github you _need_ to set up ssh certificates) is still holding water.

Comment: @Edmundo I'm not sure what ssh certificates are but https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/ says connecting over HTTPS is recommended over SSH so I haven't been looking at that and not sure that I should.

Comment: Hmm.... interesting. I've always used ssh transport. Thanks for the clarification. Given that I have no experience using https, I guess I'm giving up. :-) Consider using ssh instead (could try to set it up as a separate remote).

Answer (score 2):

> I've tried looking up instructions on how to handle this error, used git remote add proj `https://github.com/username/proj.git`

You added a remote names proj so you have to push to it

```
# push the remote named proj
git push proj master
```

If you wish to rename the proj to origin use this:

```
# rename the remote
git remote rename proj origin
```

If you wish to review your remotes:

```
# display the list of the current remotes
git remote -v

# or:
git remote show origin
```

Comment: Interesting, I've just kind of been copying what everyone else does and don't fully understand what `origin` and these other things mean or do.  That clarifies some, so thank you for that.  However, when I do `git push proj` it tells me `fatal: the current branch master has no upstream branch.`

Comment: Just looked up this error, tried the command `git push -u proj` and get the same error as before.

Comment: you have to add the name of the branch 'git push proj <branch_name>'